# Is a matrix that is symmetric and has all positive eigenvalues always positive definite?

Tags: matrices

I know a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if every eigenvalue is positive. However, is a matrix that is symmetric and has all positive eigenvalues always positive definite? More specifically, I have the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}3& -1 \\-1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Its eigenvalues are $4$ and $2$, and it is symmetric. Is it positive definite? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it sure is.

Comment: Use that the underlying space has a basis consisting of eigenvectors of the matrix.

Comment: That's what "if and only if" *means*.  That is, "a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if every eigenvalue is positive" means that "a symmetric matrix is positive definite if every eigenvalue is positive" *and* "a symmetric matrix has positive eigenvalues if it is positive definite".

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

This follows from the *if and only if* relation.

Let $A$ is a symmetric matrix. We have:

$A$ is positive definite $\iff$ every eigenvalue of $A$ is positive

It is a two-sided implication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in the real case.

Let $ A $ be a matrix that is symmetric and has all positive eigenvalues. Then,  $\forall x\in V, x^TAx > 0 $. This is true for  all eigenvectors $ x_i $ of $ A $. Hence $0<x^T_iAx_i=x_i\alpha_i x_i=||x_i||^2\alpha_i $, so $\alpha_i> 0 $.

Suppose $\alpha_i> 0\forall i $.  Then, on eigenvectors, $0<x^T_iAx_i$. $ A $ is real and symmetric.  Hence, in $ V $ there exists an orthonormal basis of $ A $, by the spectral theorem. In this basis, $\forall y\in V, y=\sum a_ix_i $. The above relation thus gives $ y^TAy=\sum a_i^2\alpha_i> 0 $. Q.E.D.